# Unable to delete custom field using force:source:delete CLI command

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, force-cli

I realize the command is still in beta, but I am unable to delete a custom field using the `force:source:delete` command.

I have tried `force:source:delete -m CustomField:myObject__c.myField__c`, which results in the error `ERROR:  Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

And I have tried `force:source:delete -p .\objects\myObject__c\fields\myField__c.field-meta.xml` which returns a `No results found` message.

Needless to say, in neither case does the field get deleted (note that I have deliberately omitted the `-u` parameter in the above examples for simplicity).

Finally, as an aside, the `-p` parameter I find problematic because if you have deleted the field in your scratch org the corresponding metadata file is also deleted, which means that there is no metadata file to point to when attempting to delete from a sandbox. I suspect the `-m` parameter also implicitly assumes that a metadata file exists (which it does in case anyone is thinking I have removed it - in fact, the same error results regardless). What makes more sense (at least to me) is to have say a `-x destructiveChanges.xml` type parameter.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87340/discussion-on-question-by-raccoon-i-unable-to-delete-custom-field-using-forceso).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in the CLI plugin for windows that you might want to report to salesforce CLI team by creating a case or via twitter.

However there is a simple workaround for it using mdapi commands that will work .

Follow the below steps

1.Create a directory named destroy .

2.Create a package.xml file as below in the above directory .Name the the file package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <version>44.0</version>
 </Package>
```

3.Create another file named as destructiveChanges.xml as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <types>
    <members>ObjectName__c.Field_Name__c</members>
    <name>CustomField</name>
   </types>
  <version>44.0</version>
</Package>
```

4.Run the command as below

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d destroy -u <alias> -w -1
```

Comment: That works, and aligns more with my preference for maintaining a `destructiveChanges.xml` manifest anyways. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You may want to mark answered so helps communication

Comment: It is a pity that it still doesn't work. I didn't plan to maintain a destructiveChanges.xml but I am forced to